# Quarter reputation > Lifetime reputation

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

I suddenly noticed my quarter reputation is somehow bigger than total reputation. How can it be possible?

I registered in this [fantastic] site on January and feel there must be something wrong on the calculation appearing on [Use Reputation League per Quarter](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2013-01-01/1983854#1983854)

[image: My unbelieveable reputation]

Thanks for keeping this up!